# What happened to the Nice / Good Answer badges?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, nice-answer

I just got a Guru badge for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508945/can-anyone-explain-this-strange-behaviour/2509174#2509174), and I still (after 3 hours) haven't gotten Nice Answer and Good Answer badges for it.

Similarly, Eric Lippert got an Enlightened badge for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2508828/where-to-learn-about-vs-debugger-magic-names/2509524#2509524), but still hasn't gotten a Nice Answer badge for it.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible that answers for which you received Nice Answer and Good Answer have been deleted.  When the badge process runs, it checks to see if you have the correct number of a given type of badge, and only if you have fewer than you should does it award one.

So if a previously marked Nice Answer was deleted, then you met the requirements again, it wouldn't award you with another one until you had more Nice Answers than you have Nice Answer badges.

According to your user page you have 52 answers voted 10 or higher, but 54 Nice Answer Badges.

While your old badges will not be taken away, you will not receive another Nice Answer badge until after you have 55 answers with a vote total of 10 or more.

Comment: That doesn't explain the missing Good Answer badge; I never had a deleted answer > 25 votes.

Comment: @SLaks: you have 4 Good Answer badges, and 4 answers with 25 points or more (155, 46, 37, 31). What are you missing?

Comment: @RegDwight - No, he has 5 answers 25 and above, but only four Good Answer badges.  One of the answers is community wiki, though, so I'm trying to find out if these badges are awarded for CW answers.

Comment: @RegDwight: The Community Wiki one is 3 different answers, none of which have 25 votes individually.

Comment: @Pollyanna: look closer. The fifth answer you are referring to is not a single answer with 40 points, it's three answers that have 40 points combined but fewer than 25 points each.

Comment: @SLaks @RegDwight - ah, there's the answer then.  There are only 4 answers eligible for Good Answer.

Comment: Is there any way to find the deleted answer?

Comment: In general, badges are awarded for CW posts just like normal ones. (My "Great Answer" badge on SO came from a CW post.)

Comment: Hm, this prompted me to look at my own, and it looks like I have one fewer "nice answer" badge than actual "nice answers".  One of my "nice answer" questions was deleted about a week ago (but is not included in the aforementioned tally).  Could it be that the badge system is, er... "overcompensating" for deleted questions/answers?