# New badge notifications targets wrong post for "Nice Answer"

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

I like the [new feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88/find-out-which-question-answer-awarded-you-the-badge) when I get a badge telling me which answer it was. However recently the links for the "Nice Answer" badge seems to be giving links to the *previous* post that got (or should have gotten) this badge rather than the most recent. This has happened every time for a while now.

- I know that badges are awarded after a delay but I don't think that's happening here - there's a strong correlation between a post getting 10 or more votes and a badge being awarded a few minutes later (but not for that post).
- I know that [deleted answers cause you to lose a badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43851/what-happened-to-the-nice-good-answer-badges/43854#43854), but I don't see how that fully explains the behaviour. I think I should have caught up again by now.

Here's a couple of screenshots that I hope clarify things:

[image]

[image]

As you can see about 1 hour ago I got 10 upvotes for [How do I create a join which says a field is not equal to X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3293939/how-do-i-create-a-join-which-says-a-field-is-not-equal-to-x/3293974#3293974) and also a "Nice Answer" badge for [Why can I not "see" this enum extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287736/why-can-i-not-see-this-enum-extension-method/3287764#3287764).

About 15 hours ago I got 15 upvotes for [Why can I not "see" this enum extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287736/why-can-i-not-see-this-enum-extension-method/3287764#3287764) and a "Nice Answer" badge for [Gotchas when making use of Nullable<T> in C# 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285495/gotchas-when-making-use-of-nullablet-in-c-4/3285540#3285540).

This pattern continues, with the upvotes and the badge being awarded at about the same time but for different questions. I couldn't find a similar issue here but I'm wondering has anyone else reported this issue? And can it be fixed so that it behaves as I'd expect?

It doesn't bother me much but it is a bit confusing and I guess I'm not the only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like we need to resync your badge reasons.

As it stands we never clear out reasons from the reason table. I'm betting there is an invalid reason in there which is causing this to happen. Since its in there, it means the valid reason is not finding its way in.

It's a very tricky thing though cause over time reasons may become not relevant and if we clear them out we may never be able to discover them again. Eg. Think tumbleweed.

I think the simplest fix here is to assign reasons in reverse order so it "feels" more correct.

**EDIT**

Fixed

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If you make a fix then let me know and I'll tell you if it works for me.

Comment: @waffles: Did you change anything? I didn't get a Nice Answer badge for my last-but-one nice answer, and now things seem to be in sync again: I just now got a nice answer badge that was for the right question.

Comment: @Mark, yerp I fixed it on Monday

Comment: @waffles: Thanks. It's much more logical now.

Comment: @waffles: Did you take a look here? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63514/badge-notification-targets-wrong-post-for-nice-answer-for-upvotes-to-old-answer The Nice Answer badge notification is everytime for one answer behind. It just occurred to me again.

Comment: @BalusC ... yerp its in my queue

Comment: @waffles: Okay, thank you for letting me know :) I'll sleep better tonight.