# "Nice Answer" badge roulette

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

This is closely related to [this question.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57824/new-badge-notifications-targets-wrong-post-for-nice-answer)

It seems my "nice answer" badges are out of sync too, as in the related question.

I just got a notification informing me that I received the badge for [an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57824/new-badge-notifications-targets-wrong-post-for-nice-answer) that reached 10 votes many moons ago, while the one that recently achieved 10 upvotes is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692532/calcuate-x-y-point-that-2-moving-balls-will-collide/3694084#3694084).

Except for some maniac tendency to tidiness, the whole matter doesn't disturb me that much :), but I *think* it may be related to a "nice answer" badge I received some time ago, and the question was subsequently deleted. I don't have a pointer to that question, but perhaps the developers can trace it [from my "nice answer" badge board](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=353410).

Although this issue is already known, I am reporting this as a bug just to inform about the possible correlation among the deleted question and the out-of-sync.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "make up badge" is no longer the case - we will appropriately award badges now for things that qualify as they qualify **completely independently of past badges**.  The old code literally counted badges, did a diff and assigned new ones...all badge queries now get and compare each individual cause (post, tag, whatever the "thing" is) and award appropriately.

Comment: Very nice! I switched the accepted answer to this one to reflect the new status. Thanks!

Comment: Is [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1381/187824) obsolete then?

Answer (score 2):

Robert Harvey♦ [said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76374/does-loss-of-reputation-cause-loss-of-privileges)  "You always get to keep a badge, once earned. However, if you lose the requirements for that badge, your next badge earned in that badge category is a "makeup" one."

thus, you gained the badge for a deleted post, kept the badge, but when you gained another identical badge that one was linked to the one that you lost requirements for.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But reporting "you right now earned badge X" from an old answer seems (at least) untidy.