# Will I lose a badge if I remove the question I earned it on?

Tags: support, badges

Let's say I get a *Popular Question* badge on one of my questions. If I remove that question, will I lose that badge?

Comment: Please do not use `\`code\`` for what is not code. Also please note that English uses whitespace *after* punctuation (like a comma or a question mark), not *before* it. Finally, please [don't use line breaks when you want to start a new paragraph](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-should-users-have-to-press-return-twice-to-insert-new-lines/45635#45635), but use an empty line instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Only tag badges are revoked. So you won't lose the badge. <s>If you delete a question with Popular Question badge then it won't be revoked but if you earn the same badge again for another question, it will be adjusted with that question.</s>

Comment: I think it was changed at some point so "if you earn the same badge again for another question, it will be adjusted with that question" might not be true anymore. Need to search and confirm. :)

Comment: [Confirmed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187740/152859)

Comment: Nice find @Sha :)