# Can the Revival badge be awarded to more than one answer to the same question?

Tags: support, badges, revival-badge

The description of the Revival badge says

> Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more

And the [full description](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) says

> Your answer must reach a score of two before any earlier answer to the same question reaches a score of two

So why was I awarded the Revival badge for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18689790/1127114), when [fyjham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18689852/1127114) garnered two upvotes before mine did? (fyjham was awarded the badge as well.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your answer is the earlier post of the two, by 10 minutes. There are no earlier answers.

The description reads:

> Your answer must reach a score of two **before any earlier answer to the same question** reaches a score of two.

Emphasis mine.

Since you received 2 upvotes and your answer is the earliest (but still posted over 30 days after the question was asked), you received the badge.

fyjham's answer was posted after yours, and because it reached 2 votes before yours did, that user was **also** was awarded [the same badge for the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/837/revival?userid=214252). At the time of the second vote, your earlier answer had not yet reached 2 upvotes so the answer qualified **as well**.

The full description you yourself linked to *also* says:

> - For the purposes of the above rule, "earlier" refers to the submission time of the first revision ([source](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1220/double-revival-techiyat-hameitim/1221#comment3255_1221)).

where the *source* link points to a comment by balpha (SE developer) that explains the exact same situation:

> When Menachem's answer had two upvotes, Alex' had only one, so Menachem got the badge. Only then did Alex' answer get the second upvote, so suddenly his answer (because it's the older one) was the one eligible for the badge, and thus he got it. While Menachem's answer now isn't eligible for the badge anymore, we don't take badges away once they're awarded. Similar example: If you get a nice question badge, but then get downvoted to only have +9, you keep the badge as well.

So yes, the badge can be awarded to multiple answers on the same question, if those answers reach 2 votes in reverse order of posting.

Comment: According to the full description of the badge, Revival is based on the time of the upvotes, not the time of the answers. Also, fyjham got the badge as well. Surely two answers can't both be "first".

Comment: @MichaelLiu: no, it is based on the time of posting. You are not parsing that sentence correctly.

Comment: maybe it should be changed to "Answered more than 30 days later as first answer, scoring 2 or more"

Comment: @Doorknob: no, because fyjham also earned it.

Comment: Wait, so does fyjham not qualify for the badge anymore? will his Revival count go up if he qualifies again?

Comment: @Doorknob: yes, that rule (not award a badge again if you are no longer qualifying for a previous) was abolished a while ago.

Comment: @MichaelLiu: note that the full description you link to also says: *For the purposes of the above rule, "earlier" refers to the submission time of the first revision ([source]([Double Revival: Techiyat HaMeitim!](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/3255)))*

Comment: @MartijnPieters: So this means that *every single answer* to a question can get the Revival badge, as long as they get to two upvotes in reverse order of being answered?

Comment: @MichaelLiu: if they were all posted 30 days after the question, then yes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wait, no, that comment just says that they're not taken away. Say you get badge X, and then you don't qualify anymore, and then you get it on a different post, you'll still only have one badge X.

Comment: @Doorknob: it also explains that the older answer still gets the badge after receiving two upvotes, which was why I added that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, but what I meant is that if the first badge-getter gets another Revival badge, his Revival badge count won't increase

Comment: @Doorknob: I cannot find the reference right now, but the rule that you don't get a *new* revival badge because an older one no longer applies, has been done away with. You *will* get another revival badge.

Comment: @Doorknob: it was *once* true, but is no longer true today.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hmm, okay then. Trying to find reference. When was this changed?

Comment: @Doorknob: I [revised the badges FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/17854/revisions) at the time, which gave me this link: ["Nice Answer" badge roulette](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187740)

Comment: Okay, so this may be how the badge *actually* works, but I would *expect* it to only be awarded to the first answer to get a score of 2 -- because, after all, that answer is the one which "revived" the question...

Comment: @MichaelLiu: the badge is there to promote answering older questions and is relatively easy (bronze); does it really matter that much?

Comment: No, it doesn't. :-)

Comment: However, the short description of the badge is definitely misleading: "Answered more than 30 days later as first answer scoring 2 or more".

Comment: It's only slightly wrong; the short descriptions often omit detail.

Answer (score 6):

Timeline of events (simplified between just you two of course):

1. Michael Liu posts answer
2. fyjham posts answer
3. Michael Liu gets one upvote
4. fyjham gets two upvotes
   **Badge awarded:** At this present time, the only answer posted earlier than fyjham's answer is Michael Liu's, which does not have a score of two. So he qualified for the badge.
5. Michael Liu gets another upvote, score of two now
   **Badge awarded:** There are no answers posted earlier than Michael's, so no matter what, he will be awarded the badge when he reaches a score of two.

Basically, when you reach a score of two, if there are no answers posted earlier than yours that already have a score of two as well, you will be awarded the badge.

---

I've updated the badge FAQ to the following:

> #### Revival
>
> - bronze; awarded multiple times
> - Provide an answer to a question that is at least 30 days old at the time of answering.
> - Your answer reaches a score of two.
> - No other answers posted earlier than your answer have a score of two. "Earlier" refers to the time the answer was originally posted (first revision).

Comment: Maybe it would clarify things to add: Multiple answers to the same question can get the badge if they reach a score of two in reverse order of being answered.

Comment: @MichaelLiu I feel like that would mostly be redundant information. The old way it was worded was somewhat confusing and vague, but I think this change accurately covers all the cases for which it can be awarded. There's nothing in there that suggests that it can only be awarded once per question.