# Why was I awarded the revival badge twice for one answer?

Tags: bug, badges, revival-badge

I am just [awarded the revival badge twice for the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/837/revival?userid=1402846).

- I checked [the Help Center](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) and [the FAQ question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68258/204869) but can't figure out why.
- I also checked [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/196936/204869) and I think I understand that it can be awarded to *multiple* answers to the same question.

But the *same* answer? Why?

Comment: As a shot-in-the-dark, what do people think happens if a post qualifies for the Revival badge, then someone revokes an upvote or downvotes (making the post now score +1), then someone upvotes (making it +2 again and still the only post with +2). Or even if this scenario can happen?

Comment: we're looking into it.. currently looks like a db hickup/race

Comment: @m0sa: I guess it wasn't fixed yet: ["Popular Question" badges being awarded multiple times on the same question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216526)

Comment: @MartijnPieters yup that was the same _strange_ event

Comment: @m0sa: I guess there is, at least, a hell of a badge cleanup job to be done there.. :-/

Comment: @m0sa I'd imagine it affects any badge given between 17:00-17:20 on 14th January, that's what I'm seeing so far.

Comment: FWIW we have the list of those cloned badges

Comment: @JamieTaylor exactly

Comment: Deleting my answer since it sounds like what I posited is not the problem (and at least from what Martijn said, can't be the problem.)

Comment: @m0sa looks like [it's back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311662/was-my-answer-really-twice-as-good-doubled-good-answer-badge), any chance to look into it? (again)