# "Popular Question" badges being awarded multiple times on the same question

Tags: bug, badges, popular-question

I've noticed that some people getting the [Popular-Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question) badge are being awarded it 4 times within a short time period.

Here are a few I found in around 2 minutes but there are countless others:

[oluies](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=203968)
[etham](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=806286)
[DanielRak](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=1193559)
[yapkm01](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=303250)
[blackguardian](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=630412)
[Cesar Bielich](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=1578347)

These all happened around the same time in the day (on the 14th)

Comment: That was reported recently....

Comment: I've had a quick look and couldn't see anything, any chance you could dig out the link for me, sorry!

Comment: Related: [Why was I awarded the revival badge twice for one answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216183)

Comment: I'd imagine as both issues happened around the same time it is the same problem, but I'd be interested in what the outcome is.