# Was my answer really twice as good? (doubled "Good Answer" badge)

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, badges

Yesterday I was awarded the same silver Good Answer badge twice. For the same post, about 5 minutes apart:

[image: double entry]

Both links lead to [the same answer post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291209/how-to-initialize-time-object-in-python/12291225#12291225). The timestamps are just under 5 minutes apart, at 2018-06-23 21:23:58Z and 2018-06-23 21:28:55Z.

This was probably some race condition somewhere, a rare bug perhaps. Assuming the extra badge was awarded in error, it can be removed as far as I am concerned. While I appreciate every badge awarded to me, I don't think it'll hurt to remove the extra badge here. :-)

I was, however, not the only one to receive double badges around that time; the following doubled badges all were awarded between 21:19:00 and 21:38:54:

- 6 double bronze Popular Question badges: [user #1](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=4754206), [user #2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=269361), [user #3](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=1207687), [user #4](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=979417), [user #5](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=824624), [user #6](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=3513521)
- 5 double bronze Nice Answer badges: [user #1](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=338986), [user #2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=338986), [user #3](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=5793905), [user #4](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=1960816), [user #5](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=7579471)
- 1 double gold Great Answer badge: [very (un)lucky user #1](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/25/great-answer?userid=1680256)

Almost surprising: there were no double *Notable Question* badges, even though there were badges awarded in that time period.

(This list was hand-compiled, so I can easily have missed some).

Comment: Same bug as [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216183/why-was-i-awarded-the-revival-badge-twice-for-one-answer), most likely.

Comment: @user202729: no, regular badges are not removed if the criteria are no longer met, only *tag badges* are.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: perhaps, but 4 years is a long time.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: on the other hand, there were at least 12 more such double badge awards at the same time.

Comment: [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9448870/?tab=badges) got Vox Populi × 2. Also 5 minutes apart. Related?

Comment: @Pang: interesting, it could well be. Which would mean that the race condition is now more prevalent. Any other double badge awards around the same time?

Comment: [Editor x 7](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3/editor?userid=9996009) | [Custodian x 6](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2278/custodian?userid=9996009), all 5 minutes apart. From [this MSO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/370192).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

As much as I'd love to be able to write a decent answer here describing what happened, there's no way to reliably reconstruct that given how much time has passed. On the upside, it appears that whatever the issue was... it's been fixed and the badge counts are correct now.

Thanks for the report! If this happens again, please post a new one.